# I'm making a simple arithmetic game that keeps generating two operand and a operator as long as the user inputs right answer to the arithmetic

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code that is randomly generating the operand and operator:

```
function gameLogic() {
  var mySymbol = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%']
  number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  operator =
  mySymbol[Math.floor(Math.random() * mySymbol.length)];

  exp = number1 + operator + number2
  answer = Math.floor(eval(exp))
  //alert(answer)

  document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = number1;
  document.getElementById("operator").innerHTML = operator;
  document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = number2;

  document.getElementById("maininput").focus();
  document.getElementById("maininput").select();
}
```

This is function that gets invoked when user press start game button(the start game button is the initial page):

```
function startGame() {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'block';

  gameLogic()
}
```

This function controls the onkeypress actions:

```
document.onkeypress = function returnAnswer() {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
    var x = document.forms["main"]["answerForm"].value;
    //alert(answer);
    if (x == answer) {
      //continue Game
      startGame();
    } else {
      alert("Game Over");
    }
  }

}
```

answer is global variable set to 0 initially.
The code is displaying two operand and one operator initially, then when i press enter to submit, if the answer is correct, instead of just changing the operand and operator, it displays the main page with start game button again. Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

As Teemu mentioned, you submit the form on the enter keypress. When that happens the page which is defined in the `action` attribute on the form will get loaded. If none is provided, the page will just reload and your game will therefore restart.

Either don't use a `<form>` element, or listen on the submit action of the form and prevent the propagation of the event.